# Varying content with CLPlacemark, administrativeArea, iOS6/iOS7

Tags: ios, core-location, ios7, xcode5

I'm planning to make an app for ios7, and have an issue with the administrativeArea Placemark Attribute.

For iOS6 i get the full name of the administrative area (ex. "California"), but for the iOS7, I get the value of "CA". This is a problem when its so varying. Is there any way I can control this input so its more consistent?

The apple docs doesnt eigher explain this in details..
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLPlacemark/administrativeArea

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can only parse it to uoy needed value.
I can offer you find the list of administrative areas with full name and with little.
After you can add this in 2 .txt files, import them in project,create 2 NSArrays and initialize each array in cycle.
After you can check administrative area name and return right value.

Comment: OK, so it's no parameters that can be sent to get the wished formatting in the first place? I'm very thankful and interested in the files, but wonder how this applies to the whole world and future maintenance?