# IOS Upgrade to 7.0 Issue With Dictionary Lookup

Tags: ios, dictionary, location

Using location Manager in an app the following code worked prior to iOS7, now with iOS7, I'm getting the "??" escape.  I'm looking up the state to retrieve the state abbreviation.  The location mananger is properly retrieving the State (if I code to use "state" it will give me the desired state), but the lookup to the plist file (set to dictionary object) to get the abbreviation, for whatever reason fails and gives the "??" option. Any Ideas what's up?

```
NSString *state = placemark.administrativeArea;
NSString *stateAbbreviation = [self.usStateAbbreviations objectForKey:[state uppercaseString]];
NSString *stateTarget = state;

if (stateAbbreviation) {
    stateTarget = stateAbbreviation;
}else{
    stateTarget = @"??";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300419/varying-content-with-clplacemark-administrativearea-ios6-ios7):

> For iOS6 i get the full name of the administrative area (ex.
>   "California"), but for the iOS7, I get the value of "CA".

So, it would seem, that **state** is already the **stateAbbreviation** on iOS7, so the key is different and you don't get a result for:

```
[self.usStateAbbreviations objectForKey:[state uppercaseString]];
```

According to Apple's documentation for [CLPlacemark](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_4):

> The string in this property can be either the spelled out name of the
>   administrative area or its designated abbreviation, if one exists. If
>   the placemark location is Apple’s headquarters, for example, the value
>   for this property would be the string “CA” or “California”.

So there doesn't seem to be a guarantee, one way or the other.